# Unable to build project output group Content file from project

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web-setup-project

I have a web setup project for a asp.net webapplication.
At my project output group, Primary output and Content Files were selected .
The error : when I build porject,

```
Unable to build project ouput group 'Content files from myproject(Active)'
```

Accord to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/835458 ,there is no extra file to remove.But there are so many images file,js file and some xml within my project and one txt file.What is the problem for build fail.

Answer (score 1):

after goggleing for a while,   this link  solve my problem.
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioMSIProblemsUnableToBuildProjectOutputGroupContentFilesFromSOMEWEBActive.aspx